# Who will write the algebraic geometry texts that are needed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Readers of MO are probably aware of the pedagogic need that would provoke such a query. It's around 60 years since Serre's FAC, and I imagine some people would say "you still have to read the original papers". There are well-known issues with the EGA/SGA material, and they can be met only by extensive rewriting. While there are some highly competent (IMO) authors dealing with aspects, an integrated treatment seems a long way off.

So, who has an overview? And who might be able to pull together a treatment of the whole area? We've come a long way since Zariski's *Algebraic Surfaces*, in particular, which de facto drew a line under the Italian school.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the question. What is wrong with EGA/SGA? Besides, there are textbooks on AG which were written recently (Liu, Görtz-Wedhorn).

Comment: @Martin: nothing is wrong with EGA/SGA but there is room for improvement. For example  in the organization (Chapter 0 is scattered all over the volumes and  the most profound and original  result on tensor products of fields is hidden in the Errata!), motivation, number of exercises and  drawings ...Don't forget that EGA/SGA is a preliminary  draft of an integrated  definitive treatise that never saw the light (cf. the complete reorganization of Chapter I as a thick book published by Springer).

Comment: I don't really see how this question can be answered in a meaningful way. Are you just looking for thoughts on who would be able to write a good AG book, e.g., 'Ravi Vakil'? Also, what's wrong with the textbooks of Hartshorne, Liu or Görtz-Wedhorn?

Comment: There is also  our friend's Donu's [new book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=FQslb7pH8EgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=donu+arapura&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=_v9yT56oE4Ss8gP06IF1&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=donu%20arapura&f=false), which is unique in its emphasis on the links of algebraic geometry with holomorphic manifolds.  

Comment: @Martin. Yes, you don't understand the question, because you don't understand why EGA/SGA, a project started more than 50 years ago, should be rewritten for pedagogic reasons. That is because it has always been very difficult to learn from, for most mathematicians.

Comment: Dear Charles, I'm not sure that it's realistic to expect a unified treatment of the type your question is yearning for.  In addition to the texts already mentioned in comments, there are the recent books by Lazarsfeld, on Positivity, and by Kollar, on Resolution of Singularities.  I think that good books like these on slightly more specialized topics are more realistic to hope for, and may also be of real pedagogical benefit: by presenting a less monolithic front, they may make the subject accessible to a wider range of students.  Best wishes, Matthew

Comment: @Emerton, indeed, this is one type of answer I'd expect: specialists can write texts in their area of expertise. But how about taking the point of view of the consumer, not the producer? In other fields, in fact, the situation would be considered fairly scandalous.

Comment: What about the stacks project?

Comment: I voted to close this as subjective and argumentative; I really don't like the tone of the question, nor of the subsequent comments by the OP. As to the substance, there are introductory texts at several levels; among the new ones, Liu's book comes to mind as a particularly good example. After that, one can very well read EGA and SGA, and a host of other books.

Comment: I don't really feel I know that much algebraic geometry, but I think one can learn a lot from the books by Miles Reid, Shafarevich, Mumford (yellow and red, and volume II edited by Oda), Kempf, and Hartshorne.

Comment: "This correspondence is closed". The topic turned out to be divisive (some upvotes while others decided it wasn't a real question). I was learning while the "Red book" was still red: the "real question" would be who is Mumford's successor, with that way of connecting Bures-sur-Yvette with Harvard, geometry with algebra, classical with modern.

Comment: Dear Charles, The question of Mumford's successor is an interesting one, although it probably would also be considered unsuitable for this site.  I'm not sure that it has an answer though, and I'm not sure that it needs one.  The situation now is different from when Mumford was writing: scheme-theoretic methods are not the mystery they were then, and people just learn them (primarily from Hartshorne, in my experience, but perhaps now from Ravi Vakil's notes as well).   Then they can (and do) go on and learn the part of geometry that interests them.  [Just one person's view.]  Best wishes, Matt

Comment: Shrug. We need to agree to differ here. 

Comment: @Angelo : Well, there are people whom , I noticed , who get more pleasure in closing down or voting down some question, rather than trying to re-construct the question ( or re-interpret )  in a meaningful manner or helping the OP, to the extent they can ! I hope you are not one among them. I saw the question of @Charles Matthews, makes more sense, and he wanted to know whether there is some room for improvement in the EGA/SGA material, and the question is well posed , but we have to step into his shoes and think , then we understand the dire need to formulate such questions ! (Cont'd)

Comment: (Cont'd) Of course, @Charles Matthews, is a senior mathematician , and has been assisting Wiki projects , and I am sure that he gauges the meaningfulness of a question before posting and then post it ! If this is not a real question, I am sure that he himself wouldn't have posted it, and nevertheless he wont get '6' up-votes . I don't agree completely in closing this question, that too with a tag 'not-real'. Of-course it makes much sense, but one has to re-read it one more time, and I am sure that he understands the nub of the question !

Comment: @Angelo : Well, I have flagged your comment as offensive , I didn't like your tone of expressing your views on OP. I am sure that , OP knows about the books you have suggested and he knows the order of reading . Of course, I hope that you wont be too offended, if I point out sincerely that, isn't this question better than the other questions ? which are ask for some "date" , and inquiring, when someone wrote something etc .  

Comment: @ everyone : Is there any chance to re-open this question ? 

Comment: I'm not a geometer, but I think Angelo's comment and the closing of the question are both completely reasonable.

Comment: To Shanmukha: I am sorry you felt that my comment was offensive, but I stand by it, and feel that there is not need to reopen this thread. And I *do* take offense at your implication that I get pleasure out of closing down questions. 

Comment: I am no longer a mathematician in fact. I think I can see this "issue" from both sides. 

Comment: **Meta** thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1481/who-will-write-the-ag-text/

Comment: @Angelo : Well, you can read that I counted you among the persons who don't derive pleasure in down-voting. Please re-read my comments, especially this line " I hope you are not one among them....." , well any how I am shifting to MO[meta] for further discussion ! Mazel Tov ! 

Comment: I surely suspect that the '4' down-votes noticed on the question is purely due to vendetta . What a pity that people are separated by narrow things , I have nothing more to say ! 